# How to pipe a data stream into a function that's assigned to a constant?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-speech-api

The example below from Google works but it uses `pipe`. For my situation I'm listening to a `websocket` that sends packets in 20ms increments and from what I've been able to find there is no way to `pipe` that data into a function.

The first argument that must be passed on initialization is a `config` object. After that only data is accepted. So I set the function up as a variable, then pass the config. But I can't figure out how to pass the stream of data into it afterwards. How do I pass data into `recognizeStream` without using `pipe`? Or is there are a way to use `pipe` with `websocket`

I can vouch for this setup working by reading and writing from temporary files at certain intervals but this has the obvious disadvantages of 1) all of that overhead and 2) most importantly, not being a real-time stream.

There are two solutions that I think would work but have not been able to implement:

1. There is some way to setup a `pipe` from `websocket` (This is ideal)
2. Simultaneously writing the data to a file while at the same time reading it back using `createReadStream` from a file using some implementation of `fs` (This seems like a minefield of problems)

tl;dr I need to send the stream of data from a `websocket` into a function assigned to a `const` as the data comes in.

**Example setup from [Google Docs](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/streaming-recognize)**

```
const Speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

// Instantiates a client
const speech = Speech();

// The encoding of the audio file, e.g. 'LINEAR16'
const encoding = 'LINEAR16';

// The sample rate of the audio file, e.g. 16000
const sampleRate = 16000;

const request = {
  config: {
    encoding: encoding,
    sampleRate: sampleRate
  }
};

const recognizeStream = speech.createRecognizeStream(request)
  .on('error', console.error)
  .on('data', (data) => process.stdout.write(data.results));

// Start recording and send the microphone input to the Speech API
record.start({
  sampleRate: sampleRate,
  threshold: 0
}).pipe(recognizeStream);
```

**Websocket setup**

```
const WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server
wsServer.on('connect', (connection) => {

  connection.on('message', (message) => {

    if (message.type === 'utf8') {

      console.log(message.utf8Data)

    } else if (message.type === 'binary') {

       // send message.binaryData to recognizeStream

    }
  })
})
```

Comment: You should just be able to do `recognizeStream.write(message.binaryData)`.

Comment: Wow, I feel both ecstatic and stupid that that worked. It worked perfectly. Thank you! Put it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to do:

```
recognizeStream.write(message.binaryData)
```